How to Capture/Text Recognize the Remote LED/LCD display characters in iOS Swift
Need to process the image, get the text from the Remote LED/LCD display Image. Tried a Vision Kit but as per this link:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651059?answerId=615679022#615679022
It's not possible to capture it.


Trained data using Tesseract.
So Tried the create a ML, not sure about which option need to check. Selected Object detection, its capture the remote area, But not able to get the text.
Integrated the Tesseract trained data for LCD/LED display(used the ssd.traineddata) but I am get the proper usage of ssd.traineddata.
Code using tesseract:
let tesseract: G8Tesseract = G8Tesseract(language: "eng")!

tesseract.delegate = self

tesseract.charWhitelist = "0123456789:"

let imageCheck = UIImage(named: "remote1.jpg")

let scaledImage = imageCheck?.scaledImage(1000)

let preprocessedImage = scaledImage?.preprocessedImage() ?? scaledImage

if let tesseract = G8Tesseract(language: "eng+fra") {

    tesseract.engineMode = .tesseractCubeCombined

    tesseract.pageSegmentationMode = .auto

    tesseract.image = preprocessedImage!

    tesseract.recognize()

    debugPrint("Text: \(String(describing: tesseract.recognizedText))")

}

Output:
"Text: Optional(\" \\n\\n \\n\\nSET\\nCLEAR y\\nTIME (t s! AICLEAN\\n\\n \\n\\n \\n\\n \\n\\n\")"

I need a LED/LCD display values: 18 / 12: 00
It's not detect the display text. Could you please any one let me know the process of using ssd.trainedata or using ML how to achieve it.
Thanks in advance.

[mre] required, data at least.

@ChristophRackwitz Sample code and output is updated. Could you please guide me to detect the text from the LED/LCD display.
